# Check if item is in date, else print default

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of objects Im trying to get by months, my problem is not every object has date for every month.

I tried like this:

```
{% regroup object_list|dictsort:"store.id" by store as store_list %}
<ul>
    {% for store in store_list %}
    <li>{{ store.grouper }}


        {% regroup store.list|dictsort:"product" by product as product_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for product in product_list %}
                <li>{{ product.grouper }}
                    <ul>
                        {% for item in product.list|dictsort:"date" %}
                        <li>{{ item.price }} - {{ item.date|date }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This give me:

- Apple

  - iMac

    - 395 - jun. 1, 2013
    - 395 - jul. 1, 2013
    - 395 - aug. 1, 2013
    - 395 - sept. 1, 2013
    - 395 - oct. 1, 2013
    - 395 - nov. 1, 2013
  - Macbook

    - 499 - nov. 1, 2013

I would like it to display like this:

- Apple

  - iMac

    - MISSING VALUE - jan. 1, 2013
    - MISSING VALUE - feb. 1, 2013
    - MISSING VALUE - mar. 1, 2013
    - MISSING VALUE - apr. 1, 2013
    - MISSING VALUE - may. 1, 2013
    - 395 - jun. 1, 2013
    - 395 - jul. 1, 2013
    - 395 - aug. 1, 2013
    - 395 - sept. 1, 2013
    - 395 - oct. 1, 2013
    - 395 - nov. 1, 2013
    - MISSING VALUE - des. 1, 2013

Anyone knwo if it is possible to do it?

Comment: Where do you want the entries that do not have date to go?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it was unclear, but not every object has a date entry in every months, some have only a date in Nov and Des, others have a date in in every month. I would like to display a `-` character if there is no date entry in the month.

Comment: Its still confusing, can you show us your `object_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem with a template filter:

1. Create a file for the filters (i.e. `<YOUR_APP>/templatetags/<YOUR_FILTERS>.py`) and add following code:

   ```
   from django.template import Library
   from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime

   register = Library()

   @register.filter
   def full_month_price_list(value):
       month_list = [[datetime(2013, i, 1)] for i in xrange(1, 13)]
       for item in value:
           month_list[item.date.month - 1].append(item)
       return month_list
   ```

   This filter takes the list of items with a date attribute and returns a list with 12 lists of 2 elements: the date and the item
2. In your template code load the filters (`{% load <YOUR_FILTERS> %}`) and change this:

   ```
   <ul>
       {% for item in product.list|dictsort:"date" %}
           <li>{{ item.price }} - {{ item.date|date }}</li>
       {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```

   by (**UPDATED to format as table as you request in comments**):

   ```
   <table>
       {% for item in product.list|full_month_price_list %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{ item.0|date:"b. j, Y" }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.1.price|default:"MISSING VALUE" }}</td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
   </table>
   ```

   Note that you access to any property of the product `item.1.date`, `item.1.price`, `item.1.pk`, etc.

Replacing `<YOUR_APP>` by the name of your django app, `<YOUR_FILTERS>` by the name you want to use for your filters file.

Note that a file named `__init__.py` is needed in the directory `<YOUR_APP>/templatetags/`.

More about custom filters in [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried your code, but I get a `list assignment index out of range` error. Any idea what could be wrong? http://pastebin.com/qWvR5MaD

Comment: I see your change in the question, If you want `"MISSING VALUE - "` it need some minor changes in my answer

Comment: The `MISSING VALUE - ` is not paramount, so if it would be difficult to add, don't bother. I tried your new code, and I get `list index out of range` error.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to decrease in 1 the month number to use as the list index, so it need to replace `item.date.month` by `item.date.month - 1` (the two times it appears), I will update my answer, please test again with this fix

Comment: Okay, thats working. But what if I needed to display more fields, and have each value/field in a new `<td></td>`?

Comment: I coded it acording to your question, but you can customize it to suit your need, but ok, I will change the code make it more flexible

Comment: Great! It would be really nice if the object did not have any value, it would not display anything (or MISSING VALUE)